# Serving Three.js virtual reality content with node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, three.js, static-files

I'm making an App where users can travel through different virtual reality environments. The VR content is made with Three.js, HTML, and regular javascript, so should be relatively easy to serve a static files. The VR content are in directories which are saved to disk, and users the folders have their own HTML files which are served when requested by a user (e.g. click a button to enter a new VR environment).

I have a node express server for handling user login and auth, and another one to serve the vr folders, which brings me to my question. 
When rendering the vr folders, the server is slow and lags a bit. So, I'm wondering is there a better way to do this. I've heard a lot node clusters, but I thought having two node servers would be about equal.

I've recently accepted the fact that I should have used Python as it would be more suitable to handle VR rendering.

Is there anyway to make the node serveres stronger? Or was node just not built for handling VR functionalities (such as loops, graphics etc).

Comment: I don't think that slow rendering of THREE.js code has to do with express server because that code is executed in the browser, and your express server just responds to requests for those files.

Comment: The Three.js code has a lot of heavy computations, and is being served with an Express server. Seeing as Node isn't very good at handling CPU intensive tasks, wouldn't it affect the vr execution?

Comment: Do your users access your app through browser or in some other way?

Comment: Through browser, it's a web app. There are two servers within the one node app which handles both server and client. I am considering using child processes rather than two servers..

Comment: Once your user opens your app on his machine (in browser) it sends the request to your express server, your server responds by sending the requested files back to the user, and then those files (like THREE.js code) are executed on the users machine (in browser) and not on your server. So unless your app creates api requests back to the server to do some computations and then sends the results back to the client, I think that performance of your app depends on your THREE.js code and individual user machine and not on your express server.